# RabbitMQ as Windows service: badarith error on rpc.erl

Tags: windows, cookies, service, erlang, rabbitmq

I am experiencing some problems with RabbitMQ started as a service on Windows.

- Operative System: Windows 8 (Microsoft Windows NT version 6.2 Server)
  (build 9200)
- Erlang: R16B03 (erts-5.10.4)
- RabbitMQ: 3.2.2

**Goal:** create a RabbitMQ cluster with three servers: Srv1, Srv2, Srv3.

Note: I have carefully followed the official documentation

All the following operations are executed as user "Administrator".

**FIRST SCENARIO: start RabbitMQ from command line as a background process**

I used the command "rabbitmq-server -detached" on Srv1.
Result: a file ".erlang.cookie" is created under C:\Users\Administrator
The execution of the command "rabbimqctl status" is successful and gives me the current state of the node.
I can then copy the file .erlang.cookie in the same folder on Srv2 and Srv3 and successfully create a cluster.

**SECOND SCENARIO: start RabbitMQ as a service (this is requirement I have)**

Result: the file ".erlang.cookie" is created under C:\Windows.
When I type the command "rabbitmqctl status" another file .erlang.cookie is created under C:\Users\Administrator and I receive the following result:

```
C:\Program Files\Aspect\DashBoard\RabbitMQ\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat status
Status of node 'rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: ['rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4']

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- RABBITMQ-NODE4: [{rabbit,49428},{rabbitmqctl3045334,49434}]

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqctl3045334@rabbitmq-node4'
- home dir: C:\Users\Administrator
- cookie hash: 0DLAKf8pOVrGC016+6BDBw==
```

We know that this is ok because the two cookies are different.
So I copy the .erlang.cookie file from C:\Windows into C:\Users\Administrator and I try again the same command. This time I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Aspect\DashBoard\RabbitMQ\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat status
Status of node 'rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: ['rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4']

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- RABBITMQ-NODE4: [{rabbitmqctl1178095,49471}]

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqctl1178095@rabbitmq-node4'
- home dir: C:\Users\Administrator
- cookie hash: TIuqp21HOQSoUJT8JfgRQw==


C:\Program Files\Aspect\DashBoard\RabbitMQ\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat status
Status of node 'rabbit@RABBITMQ-NODE4' ...
Error: {badarith,[{rabbit_vm,bytes,1,[]},
                  {rabbit_vm,'-mnesia_memory/0-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[]},
                  {rabbit_vm,mnesia_memory,0,[]},
                  {rabbit_vm,memory,0,[]},
                  {rabbit,status,0,[]},
                  {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                       [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]}
```

Please notice the Error at the end: "badarith" in rpc.erl, line 205.
I think that the file is Erlang\lib\kernel-2.16.4\src\rpc.erl
The function is this one:

```
handle_call_call(Mod, Fun, Args, Gleader, To, S) ->
    RpcServer = self(),
    %% Spawn not to block the rpc server.
    {Caller,_} =
    erlang:spawn_monitor(
      fun () ->
          set_group_leader(Gleader),
          Reply = 
              %% in case some sucker rex'es 
              %% something that throws
              case catch apply(Mod, Fun, Args) of
              {'EXIT', _} = Exit ->
                  {badrpc, Exit};
              Result ->
                  Result
              end,
          RpcServer ! {self(), {reply, Reply}}
      end),
    {noreply, gb_trees:insert(Caller, To, S)}.
```

and line 205 is 'case catch apply(Mod, Fun, Args) of'

**THIRD SCENARIO: start RabbitMQ as a named user to avoid it to create the file .erlang.cookie under C:\Windows**

I set the RabbitMQ service to log on as the user "Administrator", this way it does not create the file under C:\Windows but only under C:\User\Administrator.
Result: when the service starts, the file ".erlang.cookie" is created only under C:\User\Administrator.
When I type the command "rabbitmqctl status" I get the same error as in the provious case (badarith...).

**Now the question:** I have not found any information about this error (badarith).
Could anyone give me a suggestion about how to troubleshoot/avoid this?

Comment: On the "SECOND SCENARIO" the rabbitmq service is running? 

You could have some problem if you have moved the eralng.cookie files when an cluster is configured. 

Try to delete the mnesia DB and then re-join the cluster node. 
BE CAREFUL if you delete the mnesia db you will lose all your data.

Comment: Hi Gas, thanks for your answer.
I use virtual machines: for every test I start from a clean situation. No problem if I lose data.
So in the second case I didn't have a cluster: I was unable to create it. I was operating on one server. The situation was:
 1) Fresh installation of RabbitMQ on a clean server
 2) Start RabbitMQ service
 3) Copy the cookie from C:\Windows to C:\Users\Administrator
 4) etc.
I also tried:
 1) Copy from C:\Users\Administrator to C:\Windows
 2) Edit and save the two cookies with the same content
 3) ...

By the way: I am really curious about the "badarith" error.

Comment: Hi GADV, just an OT.... I noticed that you use Windows NT. So have you read this ? https://www.rabbitmq.com/platforms.html. It should be possible to run on Windows NT and Windows 2000 as well although this has not been tested.

Comment: Hi Gas, thanks for your answer. Windows 8 is part of the Windows NT family of operating systems; "Windows NT 6.2" is just its "real" name. So, I am using Windows 8 not Windows NT.

Comment: You are reading the stack trace the wrong way around: it starts with the latest call.  The `badarith` error happens [in the `bytes` function in `rabbit_vm.erl`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/rabbitmq_v3_2_2/src/rabbit_vm.erl#L98), probably because it was passed a non-numeric argument.

Comment: "You are reading the stack trace the wrong way around...": you are absolutely right, legoscia! :-) Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: as @legoscia points out, the error is because the rabbit_vm:bytes calls `*` with wrong arguments. Now mnesia:table_info(Tab, memory) will return `0` when it's called with wrong arguments, like a non existing table name: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/mnesia/src/mnesia.erl#L1926, which leaves `erlang:system_info(wordsize)` as being the culprit here

Comment: Please track https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/328